# Cannot find jvm.ini file

Tags: windows-xp, java

win xp sp3
adobe flash cs5
starting the application, and trying to open the action window I receive the message:

> Error initializing Java Runtime Environment. You may need to reinstall
>   Flash

I reinstalled flash and java, checked the java version (online validation) - seems ok, but the above message remains.
On some sites i found that I need to change something in jvm.ini file, but I cannot find that file on my comp (search all disk in win explorer, hidden and system files included).

Any help, pls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your documents and settings are on a different hard drive?

On Windows XP it should be located here: 
`%DRIVE ROOT%\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Application Data\Adobe\Flash CS5\language\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\jvm.ini`

On Windows Vista or Windows7: 
`%DRIVE ROOT%\Users\user\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS5\language\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\jvm.ini`

(You might need to turn on the `show hidden files`)

Once you locate it, open the `jvm.ini` and change -Xmx128m to -Xmx256m, save the file, and restart Flash IDE.